# Optimizar actualización de más de 2500 registros sin que el servidor agote su tiempo límite

Tags: php, mysql, update

Tengo una base de datos de mas de 2500 usuarios de los cuales hago una serie de consultas e inserciones por cada uno de ellos para al final obtener una calificacion y luego esa calificacion mostrarla, pero el servidor se cuelga al procesar toda esta información.

¿Existe una manera de mejorar un procesamiento de datos de este tamaño?

Nota: Ya usé `array_chunk` para partir el array de datos de 500 en 500, pero aún así, se sigue colgando el servidor.

Comment: Muestra tu consulta por favor

Comment: para procesar y manipular datos siempre que puedas dale trabajo al motor de db, para eso está hecho y suele ser muy bueno con eso. Sin ver el tipo y forma de transformación de datos es difícil dar una respuesta. 2500 registros en memoria debería ser un trabajo trivial y dentro de los tiempos esperados (por lo general uno habla de cientos de miles, o millones de registros cuando la db no responde y "cuelga")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si necesitas procesar un script muy pesado y quieres aumentar el tiempo límite, php te ofrece la siguiente función, que puedas agregar a tu script:

```
set_time_limit ( int $seconds )
```

En el caso de que quieras establecer el tiempo límite a infinito, puedes establecer el parámetro $seconds a cero. Pero como menciona Francisco, lo ideal es que tu código este lo mas optimiado posible, ya que generalmente el error de tiempo agotado aparece como resultado a una mala implementación de código, pero si ese no es tu caso puedes hacer uso de la función *set_time_limit*, espero haberte ayudado. Suerte!

Documentación oficial:
http://php.net/manual/es/function.set-time-limit.php

Answer (score 1):

primero que todo para que la consulta sql sea lo mas optimizable debes verificar de que el query ligue correctamente con sus indices y estes utlizando las funciones adecuadas a tu motor de base de datos.
ahora si tu servidor agota el tiempo de respuesta lo que debes hacer es aumentar este tiempo de procesamiento en el archivo **php.ini** por parte de tu servidor. es importante que puedas pegar el error y mostrarnos el query que estas depurando a traves de php.